# Wordpress Display Issues

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am trying to use the widget 'Super Store Finder' with no luck. Well I had some luckas I can get it to work on the page it is supposed to be on, however it shows up above the header on my home page too. Thinking it had something to do with the Goodlayers theme and page builder I am using, I tried building a standalone site with WPBakery and Elementor with less luck. Keep in mind with my first theme, all I had to do was activate the theme and it started showing up. Didn't add it to a page or anything at all. I don't want to get in to the complexities of fixing the plugin. I more or less am interested in a workaround.

I am using all the latest versions of everything btw.

My big question is simply...How can I stop this plugin from showing up on my homepage?

Comment: this seems more like a question for the theme dev support team however, assuming you are using a child theme for customization, if not its highly suggested you do. I would create a function that omits those scripts from enqueuing on the homepage within your functions file using wp_enqueue_scripts and a if is not statement to check for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my search, I came across a plugin called 'freesoil Deactivate Plugins' and you can choose which page you do not want a plugin to show up on.  Easy peasy finally....